# SPDESIGN.EXE Application error The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b )

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

Sharepoint designer 2013 installed successfully on my PC without prompting any error.
After installation while opening it's showing error.

> SPDESIGN.EXE Application error The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b ).

I have preinstalled frameworks

> Microsoft.net compact framework 2.0 SP2
>
> Microsoft.net compact framework 3.5
>
> Microsoft.net compact framework 4.5.1 Multi targeting pack
>
> Microsoft.net compact framework 4.6.1 SDK
>
> Microsoft.net compact framework 4.6.1 targeting pack

Do i need to install any prerequisite before SP designer installation?

any clue, please.

I tried dependency walker as @Chelsea suggested its showing long list of errors

> Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
> Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
> Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Please check [image: screenshot]

To many dll are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b) here, the most common cause of this error is trying to load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process, or vice versa.

Check your installation catalog for incompatible DLL files and delete them if necessary.

Or you can uninstall SharePoint Designer 2013 and remove all the relative files, then [install it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) with the [Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817441/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1) again.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to install sharepoint designer SP1 also but it's showing "The expected version of the product was not found on the system"

Comment: Chelsea_MSFT, Please check updated question

Comment: @AmanAttari I suggest you uninstall all SharePoint Designer 2013 along with all installation files and start over again. Make sure you install the same bit version as the operating system.

Comment: I did it many times but no luck and i am s=installing same bit version as my system.. 32 bit give the error in the beginning

Comment: @AmanAttari You can perform a clean boot on your machine to reinstall SharePoint Designer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135 Also, make sure the installation is not blocked by any Anti-virus program. Disable Anti-virus if necessary.